# In Android, how do I remove the margins of a custom dialog?

Tags: android, xml, themes, styling

I created a new custom dialog with an oval background. However, there is a margin on the dialog which I do not know how to remove. I've tried to apply custom themes to the dialog, but so far I have not found a way to remove this margin.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What made the difference for styling was this custom style xml:

```
<style name="BokiDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```